# How do I return different response in the webflux based on whether the Flux object has elements?

Tags: flux, reactor, webflux

I know there is a function named "hasElements" on a Flux object. But it behaves a bit strange！

```java
Flux<RoomBO> rooms=serverRequest.bodyToMono(PageBO.class).flatMapMany(roomRepository::getRooms);
return rooms.hasElements().flatMap(aBool -> aBool?ServerResponse.ok().body(rooms,RoomBO.class):ServerResponse.badRequest().build());
```

```java
return ServerResponse.ok().body(rooms,RoomBO.class)
```

The second return statement can return the right things I need when the flux object is not empty,but the first return statement only returns a empty array,which likes "[]" in json.I don't know why this could happen!I use the same data to test.The only difference is that I call the hasElements function in the first situation.But I need to return badRequest when the flux object is empty. And the hasElements function seems to make my flux object empty,though I know it doesn't do this actually.

Comment: well, I think since the data taken out from the flux object to know about whether it's empty or not, the flux object has become empty. I can use collect() to make use of the elements of the flux object and at the same time I can know the number of the elements. But this costs a lot when the data is big and seems so stupid for the requirement to know whether my flux object is empty!

Answer (score 0):

well, finally I decide to call switchIfEmpty(Mono.error()) to throw an error and then I deal with the special error globally(Sometimes it's not suitable to use onErrorReturn or onErrorResume). I think this can avoid the collect operation in memory when meets big data. But it's still not a good solution for the global error handler can be hard to maintain. I'd expect someone to give a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are transforming class `Flux` to class `RoomBO`, it is one of the reasons, why you get an empty array.

If you need to return the processed list of rooms, then, I think, `collectList` should be your choice. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--

```
Flux<RoomBO> roomsFlux = serverRequest.bodyToMono(PageBO.class)
    .flatMapMany(roomRepository::getRooms);
return rooms
    .collectList()
    .flatMap(rooms -> !rooms.isEmpty() ? ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(rooms) : ServerResponse.badRequest().build());
```